# Get disks information and output to one line

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to read the information on the storage drives and would like to output the results as (on 1 line):

```
1/2 - Samsung Evo - 500GB - 4 partitions - C :, D :, E :, F:
2/2 - USB Transcend - 16GB - 2 partitions - G :, H:
```

```
On Error Resume Next
' Create a FileSystemObject
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' Provide file path
Dim result, strComputer, outFile, PropertyArr, ArrayItem
outFile = "C:\Users\MISS\Desktop\ok.txt"
' Sets computer name to the current computer name
strComputer = "."
' Setting up file to write
Set objFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(outFile, True)
' Connect to the WMI Service
Set CIMV2 = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
If Err Then
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Unable to access WMI Service."
    WScript.Quit 32
End If
' Fetch all details from Win32_computersystem
Set Win32_DiskDrive = CIMV2.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive")
PropertyArr = Array("Model","MediaType")
For Each item_PropertyArr In PropertyArr
    ArrayItem = item_PropertyArr
Next
For Each item In Win32_DiskDrive
    result = item.ArrayItem
    WScript.Echo "Result: " & result
Next

Set FSO = Nothing
```

It is empty result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the string output in the desired format, I would suggest using a template string and use `Replace()` to fill in the details.

Because you want the driveletters that are associated with each partition aswell, you need to do more than just query the `Win32_DiskDrive`, because that query does not return driveletters. See [here](https://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmi/vbscript/0054/)

The below code should do what you want:

```
Option Explicit

Const ForAppending = 8
Dim objFso, objFile, objWMIService, colDiskDrives, objDiskDrive
Dim colPartitions, objDiskPartition, colLogicalDisks, objDriveLetters, objLogicalDisk
Dim outFile, strFormat, strResult, numCurrentDrive, strMediaType, strID, strQuery, strComputer

On Error Resume Next

' set up file to write
outFile = "C:\Users\MISS\Desktop\ok.txt"

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFso.FileExists(outFile) Then objFso.DeleteFile outFile, True
Set objFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(outFile, ForAppending, True)

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts:{ impersonationLevel=Impersonate }!//" & strComputer )
Set colDiskDrives = objWMIService.ExecQuery( "Select * FROM Win32_DiskDrive" )

'set up a string as template for the output
strFormat = "{0}/{1} - {2} - {3} - {4} partition(s)"
'create a variable for the current disk count
numCurrentDrive = 1
For Each objDiskDrive In colDiskDrives
    'start building the string to output
    strMediaType = objDiskDrive.MediaType
    If IsNull(strMediaType) Or Len(strMediaType) = 0 Then strMediaType = "Unknown"
    strResult = Replace(strFormat, "{0}", numCurrentDrive)
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "{1}", colDiskDrives.Count)
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "{2}", objDiskDrive.Model)
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "{3}", strMediaType)
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "{4}", objDiskDrive.Partitions)

    'increase the current drive counter
    numCurrentDrive = numCurrentDrive + 1
    'create an arraylist to capture the drive letters
    Set objDriveLetters = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    'escape the backslashes in objDiskDrive.DeviceID for the query
    strID = Replace( objDiskDrive.DeviceID, "\", "\\", 1, -1, vbTextCompare )
    strQuery = "Associators Of {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=""" & strID & """} Where AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"
    Set colPartitions = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strQuery)
    For Each objDiskPartition In colPartitions
        'get the drive letter for each partition
        strQuery = "Associators Of {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=""" & objDiskPartition.DeviceID & """} Where AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
        Set colLogicalDisks = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strQuery)
        For Each objLogicalDisk In colLogicalDisks
            objDriveLetters.Add objLogicalDisk.DeviceID
            'objDriveLetters.Add objLogicalDisk.VolumeName
        Next

        Set colLogicalDisks = Nothing
    Next

    'add the driveletters to the output string
    strResult = strResult & " - " & Join(objDriveLetters.ToArray(), ", ")

    Set objDriveLetters = Nothing
    Set colPartitions = Nothing

    'output on screen
    WScript.Echo strResult
    'output to file
    objFile.WriteLine strResult
Next

'close the file
objFile.Close
Set objFile = Nothing
Set colDiskDrives = Nothing
Set objWMIService = Nothing
```

---

**Update**

As per your comments, you would like to not use .NET (the ArrayList) in the code. This can be done of course, but with a little bit more effort:

```
Option Explicit

Const ForAppending = 8
Dim objFso, objFile, objWMIService, colDiskDrives, objDiskDrive
Dim colPartitions, objDiskPartition, colLogicalDisks, objLogicalDisk
Dim outFile, strFormat, strResult, strMediaType, strID, strQuery, strComputer
Dim arrDriveLetters, numCurrentDrive, numDriveLetters

On Error Resume Next

' set up file to write
outFile = "C:\Users\MISS\Desktop\ok.txt"

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFso.FileExists(outFile) Then objFso.DeleteFile outFile, True
Set objFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(outFile, ForAppending, True)

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts:{ impersonationLevel=Impersonate }!//" & strComputer )
Set colDiskDrives = objWMIService.ExecQuery( "Select * FROM Win32_DiskDrive" )

'set up a string as template for the output
strFormat = "{0}/{1} - {2} - {3} - {4} partition(s)"
'create a variable for the current disk count
numCurrentDrive = 1
For Each objDiskDrive In colDiskDrives
    'start building the string to output
    strMediaType = objDiskDrive.MediaType
    If IsNull(strMediaType) Or Len(strMediaType) = 0 Then strMediaType = "Unknown"
    strResult = Replace(strFormat, "{0}", numCurrentDrive)
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "{1}", colDiskDrives.Count)
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "{2}", objDiskDrive.Model)
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "{3}", strMediaType)
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "{4}", objDiskDrive.Partitions)

    'increase the current drive counter
    numCurrentDrive = numCurrentDrive + 1
    'reset the dynamic array to capture the drive letters
    numDriveLetters = 0
    ReDim arrDriveLetters(numDriveLetters)

    'escape the backslashes in objDiskDrive.DeviceID for the query
    strID = Replace( objDiskDrive.DeviceID, "\", "\\", 1, -1, vbTextCompare )
    strQuery = "Associators Of {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=""" & strID & """} Where AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"
    Set colPartitions = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strQuery)
    For Each objDiskPartition In colPartitions
        'get the drive letter for each partition
        strQuery = "Associators Of {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=""" & objDiskPartition.DeviceID & """} Where AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
        Set colLogicalDisks = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strQuery)
        For Each objLogicalDisk In colLogicalDisks
            ReDim Preserve arrDriveLetters(numDriveLetters)
            arrDriveLetters(numDriveLetters) = objLogicalDisk.DeviceID
            numDriveLetters = numDriveLetters + 1
        Next

        Set colLogicalDisks = Nothing
    Next

    'add the driveletters to the output string
    strResult = strResult & " - " & Join(arrDriveLetters, ", ")

    Erase arrDriveLetters
    Set colPartitions = Nothing

    'output on screen
    WScript.Echo strResult
    'output to file
    objFile.WriteLine strResult
Next

'close the file
objFile.Close
Set objFile = Nothing
Set colDiskDrives = Nothing
Set objWMIService = Nothing
```

The output will be something like

> ```
> 1/4 - Samsung SSD 750 EVO 250GB ATA Device - Fixed hard disk media - 1 partition(s) - C:
> 2/4 - ST3500418AS ATA Device - Fixed hard disk media - 1 partition(s) - E:
> 3/4 - WDC WD7501AALS-00J7B0 ATA Device - Fixed hard disk media - 1 partition(s) - D:
> 4/4 - Generic Ultra HS-SD/MMC USB Device - Unknown - 0 partition(s)
> ```

Hope that helps

<sup>P.S. Best run using CScript instead of WScript, to avoid having popup messages with one line at a time</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Theo

I tried on Win10, got results. And missed the drive letter.

Do you have a way to order the system disk always at the beginning of the first line of results ?.

Comment: https://abload.de/img/0007dkod.png

It it also display window Windows Features:

https://abload.de/img/000cujlu.png

How to prevent to showing this window.

Comment: @Orion Since the code is using a `System.Collections.ArrayList` you need to install the .Net Framework. I'm a bit surprised honestly that you do not have that on your machine yet.. Without that, the list of drive letters will not work. Please update your machine and install the .Net Framework. Otherwise, a LOT of code will not work for you in future.

Comment: Do you have a way that no need .NET Framework ?. There are not many preinstalled .NET4 machines like Win10. And here, it looks like it requires .NET3.5 / .NET2.0. :)

Comment: @Orion8 I have added code in my answer to run without relying in the .NET Framework.